# Where can I find the complete list of valid syntax valid for defining a range within Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, range

I am looking for an exhaustive list of valid syntax for a range with in MS-Excel, as examples here are some I know

- A1 - The First Cell
- A1:B2 - The four cells A1, A2, B1, and B2
- A1,B2 - The cells A1 and B2
- A:A - The first Column
- A:C - The first 3 columns
- 1:1 - The first row
- 1:10 - The first 10 columns
- $A1 - The first cell with the column being absolute and the row being relative
- A$1 - The first cell with the column being relative and the row being absolute
- $A$1 - An absolute reference to the first cell
- Sheet2!A1 - The first cell on the second sheet.

I would love to see a definitive page documenting the complete valid syntax, as I have found the above through trial and error combined with point and clicking.

One example of things I want to know is if it is possible to define a range with a range to include and a range to exclude, e.g. select all of the second row excluding D2 and D3.

Thank you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excel supports

1. “classic” cell references in A1 format, 3D format and R1C1 format, where numeric cell references can be substituted by named ranges. Microsoft documents these in the [“Overview of formulas” help document](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/overview-of-formulas-HP010342750.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HP010342370#BMusing_references_in_formulas) on office.microsoft.com.
2. structured references to tables in Excel 2010 and above. These are documented in the [“Using structured references with Excel tables” help document](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/using-structured-references-with-excel-tables-HA010342999.aspx#BMstructured_references) on office.microsoft.com.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the doco - that's exactly what I was after.